# Laravel 5 Blade Custom Directive - trouble passing variable

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a Blade directive that will set a class on my table row depending on what gets passed in. The problem is that when I call it, the value of the variable is not being passed in - the literal string that I have between the parenthesis is.

In my view:

```
@row($inspection->inspection_disposition)
```

In the directive:

```
 Blade::directive('row', function($data)
    {
        var_dump($data);
           .
           .
           .
     }
```

What I see in the dump is:

> string(37) "($inspection->inspection_disposition)"

Shouldn't I see the value of that variable? That's what I want. What am I missing here?

MORE INFO:

I need to use the value of that variable in the directive, like this:

```
if($data == "hello")
{
   return something
}
elseif($data == "goodbye")
{
   return something else
}
```

This is a simplified example, but hopefully it will help to illustrate that I need to compare the value of the variable inside the directive, then determine what to do. Perhaps I need to use eval() ?

Comment: I've been trying to use eval() but I don't think that's right... Why doesn't this pass the value into the directive????

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem, I just can't pass evaluated string or variable to my custom Blade directive. It looks like , by design, it's meant to be evaluated only after a `return`. `eval()` is always dangerous approach, though.

Answer (score 3):

Blade directive should return a string that php will interprete, like this:

```
Blade::directive('row', function($data)
{
    return "<?php var_dump($data); ?>";
}
```

Comment: Ok - I understand that now. Thank you. I will update my question to better explain what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the secret:
It's not `pass by value` or `pass by reference` it's kind of like `pass by variable name`.

So think of it this way:
When you call:

```
@row($data)
```

**imagine** that you are calling:

```
$row('$data')   /* Don't actually do this */
```

Because that's how essentially laravel processes it. It's going to take the **names** of the variables you pass and insert them into the php code that you return to the view.

So like @RDev's answer, place the following (in the `boot()` function of app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php):

```
Blade::directive('row', function($parameter)
{
    return "<?php var_dump($parameter); ?>";
}
```

The `$data` variable will hold this literal value that you passed it `"$data"`. And it will swap that into your php code like so:

```
<?php var_dump($data); ?>
```

And then that php code will get inserted into your view in place of the @row blade directive.